# How can we show that there is such $g\in C^2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

> Show that if $f\in C^2 (\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ with $f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)\neq 0$ then there is a function $g\in C^2 (\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ such that $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

I've defined $$g(x) :=
\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)}{x-a}  & \text{if } x \neq a\\
f'(a) & \text{if } x = a
\end{cases}$$

and found $$g'(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{f'(x)(x-a)-f(x)}{(x-a)^2}  & \text{if } x \neq a\\
\frac{f''(a)}{2} & \text{if } x = a
\end{cases}$$

Then I tried to find $g''(a)$ to see if $g''$ is continuous:

\begin{align}
g''(a) & = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{g'(x)-g'(a)}{x-a} \\
 & = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{\frac{f'(x)(x-a)-f(x)}{(x-a)^2}-\frac{f''(a)}{2}}{x-a} \\ 
 & = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{2(f'(x)(x-a)-f(x))-f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2(x-a)^3} \\
 & = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{2(f''(x)(x-a)+f'(x)-f'(x))-2f''(a)(x-a)}{6(x-a)^2} \\ 
 & = \frac{1}{3}\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f''(x)-f''(a)}{x-a}=?
\end{align}

But we don't know whether $f'''(a)$ exists.

I've also tried Taylor and ended up with pretty much the same.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true: for $f(x) = |x|^3$ and $a = 0$ such $g$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @Adayah: sorry, I've added $f'(a)\neq 0$ now. The problem is a part of a larger exercise and I thought that $f'(a)\neq 0$ isn't relevant to this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=(x-a)g(x)$, then it should hold:
$$\begin{align}
&f'(x) = g(x) + (x-a)g'(x),\\
&f''(x) =2g'(x) + (x-a)g''(x).
\end{align}$$
Therefore, you should expect as a result:
$$\begin{align}
&g'(x) = \frac{f'(x)-g(x)}{x-a},\\
&g''(x) = \frac{f''(x) - 2g'(x)}{x-a} = \frac{f''(x)}{x-a}-2\frac{f'(x)-g(x)}{(x-a)^2}.
\end{align}$$
So your formula for $g'(x)$ is correct. However, I wouldn't expect $g(x)$ to be $C^2$, but only at most $C^1$ in general. Indeed, take
$$h(x) = \cases{0 & if x < 0\\x^2&else}\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$$
and let
$$f(x) = x(h(x)+1)  = \cases{x & if x < 0\\x^3+x&else}\in C^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
Then obviously $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$ and $g(x)=h(x)+1\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. The idea here is that "multiplying by $x-a$ reduces the degree of the discontinuity at $a$ by $1$".